# Unknown result of select command

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, select

I have multiple `.csv` files (`mydata_1`, `mydata_2`,...) with the same amount of columns and column names(, different row lengths if that helps finding an answer). After reading them into my environment they have the class `data.frame` . I was putting them all in a `list` and now want to `select` specific columns by name from all of them, resulting in in the same variable name with just the chosen columns.

```
mydata_1 = matrix(c(1:21), nrow=3, ncol=7,byrow = TRUE) 
mydata_2 = matrix(c(1:21), nrow=3, ncol=7,byrow = TRUE) 
 colnames(mydata_1) = c(paste0("X","1":"7"))
 colnames(mydata_2) = c(paste0("X","1":"7"))

df1 = as.data.frame(mydata_1)
df2 = as.data.frame(mydata_2)

all_data = c(df1, df2)

class(all_data)
class(df1)

for (i in all_data){
  i = select(i,"X3":"X5")
  }
```

My `for` command shall output the data.frames `df1` and `df2` with just three columns (instead of the prior seven), but when running the code an error message regarding the `select` command appears.

> Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

How can I get an working output of my new `df`s?

Comment: `select` is not a base R function. Per `r` tag (hover to see): *specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first issue here is that your are trying to create a list using `c(df1, df2)`, while you have to use `list(df1, df2)`

**Data**

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mydata_1 = matrix(c(1:21), nrow=3, ncol=7,byrow = TRUE) 
mydata_2 = matrix(c(1:21), nrow=3, ncol=7,byrow = TRUE) 
colnames(mydata_1) = c(paste0("X","1":"7"))
colnames(mydata_2) = c(paste0("X","1":"7"))

df1 = as.data.frame(mydata_1)
df2 = as.data.frame(mydata_2)

all_data = list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)
```

The second problem is within your loop. look, in this approach you have to create an empty list before running the loop, and then aggregate elements in each iteration.

```
all_data2 <- list()

for(i in 1:length(all_data)) {

all_data2[[i]] <- all_data[[i]] %>% select(X3, X4, X5)

}
```

try using `map` from `purrr` which is part of the tidyverse package and lead to a cleaner code with the same result.

```
# Down here the `.x` is replaced by each element of the list all_data
# in each iteration, ending wiht a list of two data frames

all_data2 = map(all_data, ~.x %>%
                select(X3, X4, X5))
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider base R's `subset` with *select* argument for contiguous column selection, wrapped in an `lapply` call. Unlike `for` loop, `lapply` does not require the bookkeeping to reassign each element back into a list:

```
all_data <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)

all_data_sub <- lapply(all_data, function(df) subset(df, select=X3:X5))
```